# How can I make dvisvgm calling kpathsea find the texmf.cnf file in a nonstandard directory?

Tags: texmf, kpathsea, dvisvgm, tinytex

`dvisvgm` calling `kpathsea` cannot find the `texmf.cnf` file, but this does exist, though at a presumably nonstandard directory location. What to do to let the `texmf.cnf` file be located?

---

To convert a `.dvi` file into a `.svg` file, the command

```
dvisvgm  -p 1 "media/Tex/2ce87d7e7c2b7157.dvi" -n -v 0 -o "media/Tex/2ce87d7e7c2b7157.svg"
```

is called and receives the output

```
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /etc/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c.
```

However, calling `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` shows that this file exists (`/home/aria/.TinyTeX/texmf.cnf`), though at not one of the listed directories of the `dvisvgm` command.

I also tried running `tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME "~/.TinyTex"` which was successful:
`tlmgr: setting texmf TEXMFHOME to ~/.TinyTex (in /home/aria/.TinyTeX/texmf.cnf)`, but running the first command still leads to the same error.

Comment: The mentioned warning comes from the kpathsea library which is also used by `kpsewhich`. Do you use a dvisvgm binary that comes with your TeX distribution or did you install it separately? In the latter case you need to ensure that dvisvgm is built with the kpathsea library matching your TeX environment. Otherwise, kpathsea doesn't know where to look for the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that makes it all work, but I am unsure if this is the intended way. I just added a symlink to the existing `texmf.cnf` file in a directory that `kpathsea` looks in, which further entailed that I actually make one of the directories, as they don't exist for me.